# accessing layout.xml through java and assigning values to views in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-resources

I am new to android programming am trying to learn it.

So basically there are two ways of creating whatever is going to be visible on the screen :-

- We create views and view group objects inside `layout.xml` files. And then as the need be we access those views that are already existing
  in the layout through our java programs by accessing their ids ( as
  r.java….). 
   So basically when we start a particular activity, we
  set the content to be displayed corresponding to that activity using
  `setContentView` method, to which we pass the `layout.xml` file, inside
  which we have defined the different views and view groups to be
  displayed on the screen.
- The second way is we create these views dynamically though our java programs and then set them as the content on the screen using
  `setContentView` again.

Now the above is my basic understanding. Please let me know if the above needs correction.

Now what I want to understand here is :-

- Is there a way that using the first method itself, we can do the
  vice-versa, as in say instead of fetching the the views through their
  ids from the `layout.xml` files, can we already have a predefined
  `layout.xml` file with different views having ids, and now through our
  java programs can we just access those views though their ids and set
  their values, something like say (in javascript) :-

  document.getElementById(“someTextBoxId”).value= “some calculated
     value from java code here”

Thanks.

Comment: A `layout.xml` file is like an html file. The equivalent to `document.getElementById("someId").value = "value"` is something like  `this.findViewById(R.id.someId).setValue("value")`. Have you read any tutorials?

Comment: Hi @rubenlop88 yes i am going though the tutorials available on developer.android.com. I came across this while trying my hands at the basics and just wondered if the above was possible. Thanks for the response.